# Does standarizing the dataset in machine learning decrease accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

At first i used normal logistic regression with iris dataset and it got me 0.977 accuracy and next time with preprocessing the dataset i got 0.955 accuracy. Why is it so?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
logreg= LogisticRegression()
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest= train_test_split(x,y, test_size= 0.3, random_state= 1)

logreg.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
ypred1= logreg.predict(xtest)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(ytest, ypred1))
```

Model with preprocessing

```
logreg= LogisticRegression()
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest= train_test_split(x,y, test_size= 0.3, random_state= 1)

sc1 = StandardScaler()
sc1.fit(x_train)
X_train_std1 = sc1.transform(xtrain)
X_test_std1 = sc1.transform(xtest)

logreg.fit(X_train_std1, ytrain)
ypred1= logreg.predict(X_test_std1)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(ytest, ypred1))
```

Comment: In theory, normalizing your data as you did should help with the fitting because the gradient descent-like algo will converge faster toward the minima. Did you actually ran the fit as long on both model? What happens if you keep minimizing the second? You should end up with the same, or higher accuracy. Anyway, quick answer, No normalization doesn't reduce accuracy. (btw I am not familiar with sklearn, and a quick look to the doc shows that StandardScaler is a normalization operation)

Answer (score 0):

**Does standardizing the dataset in machine learning decrease accuracy?**
- Short answer, No.

Data normalization is mostly related to convergence, not accuracy. However, there are models that assume specific distribution of the data, in those cases normalization may become very important.

[image]

In case 1, features are not normalized so it's a slightly longer path for the optimization algorithm, for case 2 it's equal in all direction so convergence is slightly faster, but this example applies strongly for min-max, unit-vector normalization.

Some assumptions of logistic regressions:

1. observations should be independent of each other
2. little or no multi-collinearity among the independent variables
3. independent variables are linearly related to the log odds

But, logistic regression doesn't assume normalized data. So, it's not a necessary step to fit a logistic regression model.

It will be wrong to assume, normalization will improve accuracy for the model.

Mean centering and scaling to unit variance is commonly useful, but it all depends on the properties of your data.

If your data is in an irregular manner, the mean subtraction may skew some features to a direction that leads to lower accuracy by harming any of the strong assumptions of the logistic regression such as introducing some non-linearity due to numeric reasons.